# Dynamic feature modules in Navigation Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

Since few days, I search a solution to use Jetpack Compose and Dagger with dynamic feature modules (like onDemand module : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand).

I found this issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183677219 and I read lot of documentation, so I don't have lot of hope, but with luck...

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Apparently there's no update for this so far according to them it's still in the pipeline. How I found one solution through a medium article

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/dynamic-delivery-with-jetpack-compose-c459f9227430